# Building an internal wiki on Salesforce

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, custom

Our company needs a wiki that can be accessed inside the Salesforce platform. I've explored Chatter Answers, Chatter Questions, Knowledge, and myTrailhead, but the wiki-style format is pretty important in our use case, so none of those are suitable. Has anyone built out a wiki in SF with custom code? Has anyone seen anything like this on github or bitbucket? We have some very talented developers on our team, so coding anything won't be a problem, but I'd like to understand the architecture of a potential solution and not reinvent the wheel unless absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 2):

If you define *wiki-style format* as a functional goal such *as a service that allows collaborative editing of its content and structure by its users*, then all of the options you listed allow this. Communities + Knowledge is perhaps the closest in terms of what you want. It allows collaborative edits and it has a lot of content management machinery that underlies a wiki. And, sure, yes, you can write custom code to make it more, ahem, wiki-like.

Reading between the lines of your question, it seems that you and perhaps other folks on your team have a preconceived notion of how a wiki should look and feel versus what a wiki should *do*. Could you get there with Salesforce? Perhaps..but that would be reinventing the wheel. There are a ton of OSS and commercial wiki solutions. One obvious example is [StackOverflow for Teams](https://stackoverflow.com/teams). You could simply create a tab/button/link that launches a non-SF wiki app from SF with, say, SSO and call it a day.